# For swapping should i approve 0x contract address or address from function 'getTransformerDeployer' or 'getTransformWallet'

Tags: solidity, blockchain, 0x

I am building a middleware contract to interact with 0x protocol. so for swapping tokens
should I approve(erc20 function) directly 0x address for transferring asset or the address from the function 'getTransformerDeployer'. In other words should i transfer assets from user address to 0x contract address or the address from 'getTransformerDeployer' or 'getTransformWallet'

Answer (score 0):

You approve the 0x exchange proxy address, 0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff. This is returned in [0xAPI responses](https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=USDC&sellToken=DAI&sellAmount=300000000000000000000) as `allowanceTarget`.